# pythonでのJSONデータの取得がうまくいきません。助けてほしいです。

Tags: python, json

pythonでopenweathermapから天気予報を取るプログラムの勉強をしています。ですが401エラーがでてしまい先に進むことができません。401エラーは「許可されていない」との情報をインターネットで見たのですが、サイトへのログインはしています。

ログインしているのに「許可されてない」となる理由がわからないのですが、なぜ「許可されていない」エラーになるのか、わかる方がいましたら回答いただけないでしょうか？

```
import json, requests, pprint
APPID = '-'#APIキーの定義
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={}&cnt=3&appid={}'.format('Akashi-shi,jp', APPID)
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

weather_data = json.loads(response.text)
pprint.pprint(weather_data)
```

---

解決しました。【URLの表記ミスでした】
書籍の内容と公式ドキュメントでは表記に違いがありました。今度からは公式ドキュメントは必ず確認しようと思いました。

```
# × → url ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q={}&cnt=3&appid={}'.format('London', APPID)
url ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid={}'.format('London', APPID)
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/101992

Comment: マルチポスト関連の記事は一読させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージによると有効なAPPIDが設定されてないためのようです。こちらのサービスには詳しくありませんが、下記のリンクにある指示に従ってアカウントを作成し、APPIDを取得する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

http://openweathermap.org/faq

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりでした。（この問題は解決しました。）urlの表記ミスが原因でした。追記しておきたいと思います。